# Resolving HomeController in global.asax using unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, global-asax

I have a controller that has dependency injection.

Constructor of home controller:

```
    public HomeController(ICustomer customer, ISiteSettings siteSettings, ILogger logger, ILocalizer localizer)
        : base(customer, siteSettings, logger, localizer)
    {
    }
```

I want to return an actionresult from the global.asax with the following code:

```
IController controller = new HomeController(dependency should go here);
```

and I want unity to resolve the dependency (customer, siteSettings, logger, localizer) rather than I creating the dependencies on global.asax one more time and pass it into controller.

somecode like the following should work but I havent been able to get it sorted:

```
IController controller = UnityManager.Instance.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and here is how I finally solved it:

```
IController controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, "Home"); 
controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context), routeData));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd first have to configure your Unity DI container. The common practice is to create a bootstrapper, with a static method to handle the registrations, like:

```
public class ContainerBootstrapper {
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container) {
        container.RegisterType<ICustomer, CustomerImplementation>(/* configure your class implementation here */);
        container.RegisterType<ISiteSettings, SettingsImplementation>(...);
        container.RegisterType<ILogger, LoggerImplementation(...));
        ...

    }
}
```

and call it from your global.asax

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
ContainerBootstrap.RegisterTypes(container);
```

To resolve controller in an ASP.NET MVC4 application, you need to replace the standard Controller factory implementation. For more information check out [Unity documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec17).
There is a "Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC" nuget package available, which containers a standard `UnityDependencyResolver` implementation, you just need to register it with:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: these are all done. Now I need to invoke an actionresult in global.asax and I cant find out how to resolve the controller that the actionresult is sitting in there.